# Merge Date and Time into one variable in php

Tags: php, date

I have got 2 variables like:

```
$date //2011-01-01
$full_old_date //1999-01-01 12:00:00
```

Now I want to combine the new date and the time of the $full_old_date together as a new variable like:

```
$full_new_date //2011-01-01 12:00:00
```

What should I do to extract only the time from the old one and combine them together as a new date variable?

Comment: The trick here is to concatenate.

Comment: numerous ways to do this, some more efficient than others, what have you tried?

Comment: try using [preg_split](http://in1.php.net/preg_split) to split the $full_old_date with space and concatenate it with $date to get $full_new_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps (assuming you have these values as 'strings' and not date/timestamps):

```
$date = "2011-01-01";
$full_old_date = "1999-01-01 12:00:00"
$full_new_date = $date . ' ' . trim(substr($full_old_date,-8));

//substr() - This gets the last 8 characters of the $full_old_date variables
//trim() - This function removes any whitespace at the edges of the substring
```

There are many ways to do this, however this is one way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have been using php for not a long time and I thought the "date" is some kind of special variable type. Looks like it is just a string and that's why there are so many ways. Sorry for this kind of novice question.

Answer (score 1):

This solution may help you

```
$date ="2011-01-01";
$full_old_date ="1999-01-01 12:00:00";

function newDate($date,$full)
{
    return $date . " " . explode(" ",$full)[1];
}

echo newDate($date,$full_old_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_replace like this

```
$date = "2011-01-01";
$full_old_date = "1999-01-01 12:00:00";
echo $new_date = preg_replace('/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/', $date, $full_old_date);
```